# Use HTTP/1.1 with SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, http, http-1.1

When I use HTTP/1.1 with SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, loading a page that pulls in other resources will hang after the second resource.

Here is a small reproducer:

```
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    #protocol_version = "HTTP/1.0"   # works
    protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"   # hangs

server = HTTPServer(("localhost", 7080), MyRequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

With the above server, the following HTML will hang when the browser tries to load `b.png`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="a.png">
        <img src="b.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

Can HTTP/1.1 be used with the SimpleHTTPServer module and if so, how? Note that adding ForkingMixIn or ThreadingMixIn to the server will allow things to progress, however, it seems that it should be possible without either of those mixins.

Comment: You write *Here is a small reproducer* but there's no *page that pulls in other resources* in here so I guess it can't be a reproducer. Please describe how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost it's so trivial I didn't bother posting it (any page with multiple resources will trigger it), but I posted example HTML that exhibits the problem (you'll need to provide PNGs for a.png and b.png).

Comment: What's the Python's version and OS?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost the python version doesn't matter. The question is about modifying the behavior of SimpleHTTPRequestHandler. The same behavior happens in python2.4, python2.7 and python3.2 (you just have to change the imports slightly with python3). This on Linux (multiple versions of Ubuntu and Linux Mint). I'm not using Threading or Forking MixIn so I suspect that same behavior would happen in Windows.

Answer (score 7):

The behavior you see is due to three reasons:

- `BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer` by default is capable of handling only one request at a time
- most user agents (browsers) open more than one connection to any given host at a time
- most user agents use `keep-alive` feature of HTTP 1.1 and do not close a connection immediately after they received requested entities

What you see is that browser is able to get all [entities](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7) requested using the **first** connection it opens to the server. This is the page itself and possibly some of its resources. At the same time browser opens additional connections to get the rest of resources but these connections can't proceed because the server is tied with the first one. The reason server is tied with the first one is that although browser had already received entities requested using this connection it does not close it immediately in case it could be reused to get more entities in the near future (the server does not close the connection on its side either as the browser specified version 1.1 of HTTP and sent `Connection: keep-alive` header). Only after the first connection times out, the server starts handling the next waiting connection so additional resource(s) are being downloaded (all which were requested using this specific connection). If you wait long enough the browser manages to get all resources. You can observe the difference when you set `network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server` preference to 1 (instead the default 6) in Firefox or analogous in other browsers. Then, as all resources are requested using the same connection, retrieval of each starts as soon as the previous was retrieved without any delay.

I'd like to thank *marienz* from #python IRC channel on freenode.net for his help with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this! I'd been stuck on this for days. I added a threading mixin, which appears to have solved the problem, but I still didn't understand what the problem was in the first place until I found this post.